# Final state of JQuery animation is displayed when the same page is loaded in a new browser tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm animating page entry using JQuery. When I navigated to a different page on the site and went back to the original page using the browser's back button, I noticed the final state of the page animation was being loaded. I then found out the following fixes that issue:

```
<body onunload="">
```

This worked fine, but now I noticed a different issue. When I load the page, open a new browser tab, and go to the same page, the final state of the animation is loaded as well. I'm not exactly sure what causes this and am wondering if there is a fix.

**EDIT**

Here's an animation that's causing the issue:

The following function is called by some other function with count set to 0 and array content shuffled.

```
   function EntryFadeInContainers(count, array) {

        $('#subContainer' + array[count]).fadeTo(50, 1, function () {

            $('#subContainer' + array[count]).css("display", "block");

            ++count;

            if (count != 20) {
                document.title = "shown: " + count;
                EntryFadeInContainers(count, array);
            }
            else {
                $("#mainContainer").css("display", "block");
                isPageEntryAnimationDone = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

`document.title = "shown: " + count;` is for debugging purposes only. I noticed that 9 out of 10 times IE9 won't run the recursive function when the page is loaded in a new tab.

**EDIT**

Tested it in IE10, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Which browser(s)? Can you show some code?

Comment: Currently only happens in IE9. I'll post some code in a bit.